# OnItemSelectedListener for Spinner that was added programmatically does not trigger

Tags: android, spinner, onitemclicklistener

I've got a spinner that opens programmatically. It pops up and appears to be working fine, but for some reason my OnItemSelectedListener does not trigger any of the events within it.

```
public class BeerConverter extends Activity {

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter3;
    Spinner spinner03;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        spinner03 = new Spinner(this);
        adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 

        spinner03.setAdapter(adapter3);

        spinner03.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener3());
        adapter3.add("Stuff");
        spinner03.performClick();

        }
```

Then I create the listener as a nested class:

```
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener3 implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentview, View v,int position, long id){
        curPos = position;
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Test text. If you see this, it means MyOnItemSelectedListener3 was called.";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
    {
        //do nothing
    }
};
```

So when I send the `spinner03.performClick();` the Spinner pops up correctly, but when an item in the Spinner is selected, it just closes and does not call the OnItemSelectedListener. It looks like [this person had the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331626/create-spinner-without-spinner-in-xml/6635641#6635641) a while back, but didn't ever end up posting the solution.

Comment: When/how is your spinner displayed ? In this code you just create a spinner independently from the main layout.

Comment: The spinner is displayed when I use `spinner03.performClick();` It displays fine, but the listener just won't trigger when an item is clicked. I've edited the question to (hopefully) make this more clear.

Comment: I kind of find it weird that the Spinner isn't added to the global layout, and I feel like that could be the problem. The popup is displayed, but the Spinner view itself isn't "present" in the layout. Maybe that prevents the listeners from being called. Have you considered using a Dialog with a list instead ? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList

Comment: Are you sure that `onItemSelected` is not triggered? To be sure test it with Log not Toast. You shouldn't use `getApplicationContext()`, use your activity context to show toast.

Comment: @dziobas I tested the above code with a log, and the log never shows.

Comment: I'm really new to all this, so I'm not exactly sure how to use/read logs. Is there a tutorial or example code that you could direct me to? I have also tried other things within the `onItemSelected` that do not compute. Obviously there's something wrong with the listener or the `Spinner`.

Comment: @Gregory I was not aware that I could do that. (As I said, I'm pretty new to this.)

I will attempt to simply use a Dialog with a list instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment thread above suggests, many if not all events related to a View will not behave as you expect if the View in question is not attached to a window. Do not use unattached Views to drive any sort of user interaction.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by setting spinner visibility not "Gone".