# How to call a method when spinner click?

Tags: android

I have a spinner having list of `"one","two","three"`,

I want to call a method for each selection`(that means when click spinner)` in spinner.

Is there any default method available when click spinner.So how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
        Spinner sp = new Spinner(this);         
        ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new
        String[]{"one", "two", "three"});       
    sp.setAdapter(aa);
        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    // your code here
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
    // your code here
}

});
```

Comment: if i use this code it shows error as "OnItemSelectedListener cannot be resolved to a type" i dont know why.Actually i use List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); list.add("one");, is their any problem if i use List

Comment: using List<String> is no difference to using String[]. The constructor knows to parse both cases. are you sure you are setting the setOnItem... on the spinner and not the Adapter?

Answer (score 2):

you can use  `setOnItemSelectedListener` for what you need

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    // your code here
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
    // your code here
}

});
```

Comment: i created the spinner in java code,, not in xml,,Spinner spinner1=new Spinner(this);, i use array adapter to load the lists in spinner,, if i use this method it shows error.

Comment: Errors:OnItemSelectedListener cannot be resolved to a type
 - The method setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) in the type AdapterView<SpinnerAdapter> 
  is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemSelectedListener(){})

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635732/onitemselectedlistener-for-spinner-that-was-added-programmatically-does-not-trig